# Is there a way to count bytes in this stream "passage"?

Tags: rust

Using the below code I can have the size in bytes of my (stream) file:

```rust
let bytes_copied = tokio::io::copy(&mut stream, &mut file).await?;
```

Is there a way I can have the size of the (stream) file using `rust-s3` methods (https://github.com/durch/rust-s3) ?

```rust
bucket.put_object_stream(&mut stream, filename).await?;
```

Or Is there a way to "count" bytes as they "pass" in this "stream tunnel"?

Comment: You could write a wrapper around your stream that also implements `Read`. In this wrapper, you'd increase the counter yourself on reads and forward everything else to the underlying concrete (or generic) reader. Kind of along [those lines](https://github.com/ChainSafe/forest/blob/main/utils/forest_utils/src/io/writer_checksum.rs) I implemented some time ago, but for a reader.

Comment: Isn't this what the inspect iterator/stream combinator is for? Could you use that?

Comment: MeedTitan, can you please/link an example? I don't know what are you talking about...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get callback/update when using tokio::io::copy?](/q/60621835/2189130)